# Alexa-App creating intents in seperate files and import and using them in index.js

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to make my file management a bit easier and make each intent in its own file. How do I include that so my index.js uses that intent. Heres and example of what I have tried.

```
var alexa = require('alexa-app');
var app = new alexa.app();
var GetLunchSuggestions = require('./Intents/GetLunchSuggestions');
app.launch(function(request, response) {
response.say('Welcome I am built to handle your lunch requests');
response.shouldEndSession(false);
});

app.use(GetLunchSuggestions);

// Connect to lambda
exports.handler = app.lambda();
if (process.argv.length === 3 && process.argv[2] === 'schema') {
console.log(app.schema());
console.log(app.utterances());
}
```

I want use lunch suggestions intent in this file. How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `./Intents/GetLunchSuggestions.js`

```
module.exports = {
  'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
      const speechOutput = 'I'm a handler from different file.';

      this.response.speak(speechOutput).shouldEndSession(isLaunched);
      this.emit(':responseReady');
   }
}
```

then in your `index.js`

```
const GetLaunchSuggestions = require('./Intents/GetLunchSuggestions');

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context, callback);
  alexa.appId = APP_ID; // APP_ID is your skill id which can be found in the Amazon developer console where you create the skill.
  alexa.registerHandlers(
    handlers, // this where some of your handlers being defined. You can remove this if it was not define it your code.
    GetLaunchSuggestions // this is your handler from different file.
  );
  alexa.execute();
};
```